# Pass a variable in variable with expression in expression - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

I have following expression in my code (React, Appolo, GraphQl):

```
events: {global: {worker_lname: `='somebody'`, ORDER_BY: ['timestamp DESC, id DESC']}}
```

I want to know if is it possible to use that piece of code like this:

```
let myvar=worker_lname: `='somebody'`;
events: {global: {myvar, ORDER_BY: ['timestamp DESC, id DESC']}}
```

Comment: Surely you can try and see that it doesn't work. Why ask *that*?

Comment: I've tried and it doesn't. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like this:

```
let worker_lname = 'somebody';
var events = {global: {worker_lname, ORDER_BY: ['timestamp DESC, id DESC']}};
console.log(events);
//
{
   global: {
    ORDER_BY: ["timestamp DESC, id DESC"],
    worker_lname: "somebody"
   }
 }
```

Comment: @noszone was the answer useful? If so, can you please accept it?